# 500 internal server error in login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, upgrade, login, http-error-500

In magento 1.9.1 when I am trying to upgrade to 1.9.2 on live server, it is being failed. After failed attempt for upgrade, when I try to login on admin page, it is giving 500 internal server error. Even in **`var/log`** folder also, I can't find recent logs.

How to resolve this issue? Can anyone guide me to solve the error?

Comment: error code 500 = php error, check your php/apache/nginx error logs

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have maintenance.flag file on your magento root, if that appears then please remove that file and set correct file or folder permission before you upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be permissions please give the permissions for the folders 755, and files 644, for Media and var 777 as well remove cache and session and check the same.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```